# Select product with smallest price when products are group

Tags: mysql, subquery, inner-join

Select product with cheapest price, when group by group id.
I managed to get cheapest product when all products in a group have different prices, but when all products in a group have same price it does not work. So

I need help to add a extra filter to with limit Join.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9b16c/6

[I have created a sample here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9b16c/6)

```
SELECT 
    p.id, p.price
FROM
    product p
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        product_group_id, MIN(price) AS price
    FROM
        product
    GROUP BY product_group_id

    ) AS inp ON p.product_group_id = inp.product_group_id
        AND p.price = inp.price;
```

Sample data

ID |       price |         sku       |          product_group_id

```
'58', '2800.0000', '1-67-131-72', '44'
'60', '3688.0000', '8-105-82-72', '30'
'61', '2750.0000', '9-105-82-72', '31'
'62', '3400.0000', '10-67-131-72', '45'
'189', '3530.0000', '7-113-114-115', '29'
'190', '3050.0000', '7-113-114-72', '29'
'193', '2980.0000', '7-105-114-115', '29'
'194', '2500.0000', '7-105-114-72', '29'
'196', '4699.0000', '8-116-114-115', '30'
'199', '4069.0000', '8-116-82-72', '30'
'200', '4318.0000', '8-105-114-115', '30'
'205', '3910.0000', '9-117-82-115', '31'
'206', '3230.0000', '9-117-82-72', '31'
'207', '3580.0000', '9-105-114-115', '31'
'256', '3550.0000', '1-135-136-137', '44'
'257', '3070.0000', '1-135-136-72', '44'
'258', '3400.0000', '1-135-131-137', '44'
'259', '2920.0000', '1-135-131-72', '44'
'260', '3430.0000', '1-67-136-137', '44'
'261', '2950.0000', '1-67-136-72', '44'
'262', '3280.0000', '1-67-131-137', '44'
'263', '3880.0000', '10-67-131-137', '45'
'292', '8750.0000', 'HobartAUPs-117-137', '53'
'293', '8750.0000', 'HobartAUP-69-72', '53'
'294', '8750.0000', 'HobartAUP-69-137', '53'
'295', '8750.0000', 'HobartAUP-117-72', '53'
```

Desired result

ID    |  Price

```
'194', '2500.0000'
'61', '2750.0000'
'58', '2800.0000'
'62', '3400.0000'
'60', '3688.0000'
'292', '8750.0000'
```

Comment: You said "product with smallest price" but "it doesn't work when they all have the same price" - so what do you expect your query to return when they have the same price? How do you choose the "one right product" from the thousand that are all 99p?

Comment: Some groups have products with 60p, 65p and 55p and than one group has all products as 99p. so code work with 1st group but not with 2nd

Comment: You're not getting me. You have 1000 products that are 99p, ll in the same group, and you're complaining "I asked for the one product that has the lowest price but the database gave me 1000" - the database can only give what you ask. ALL the products have the lowest price, so you got all the products. You either need to abandon the idea of getting just one product when there are multiple products with the lowest price, or you need to think of some logic that allows the database to pick one of them. If you have 99p in your pocket, how do you decide to buy the 99p eggs,99p bread or 99p milk?

Comment: I have box of 6 eggs organic 99p, free range 89p and caged 70p but I also have bread white 99p, wholemeal 99p. So on list page I want to show that I have eggs available from 70p and bread from 99p. My query can select caged 70p eggs but it also return both breads not just one and I want to just select one to show on list page.

Comment: So, any bread will do ? It could be to one with the lowest primary key id, or the first one when all breads are sorted by manufacturer name alphabetical? Or the one with the most ingredients? Or the one that sold the least last month? (these are all an example of a logic that the database can work with to return only one product, but the important thing is - the logic has been specified and can be coded in an sql. right now youre getting all the breads because that's all your sql is asking for)

Comment: Yes any bread will do. with lowest primary key or price will do. Because I will show that I have breads from 99p

Comment: Where's the desired result??

Comment: Cool - note though that the logic isn't "lowest primary key or price" - it's "price and then lowest primary key". I'm not trying to be difficult; i'm trying to explain why your first query didn't work out. Anyone can just be given an answer and paste it into their program, but it's more important (to me) that you can reason out the logic of why the answer works, so you learn and can replicate it again in future. Gurwinder's answer gives an example of this in action - he's used additional logic to return the min primary key, in cases where there is more than one result

Comment: @Strawberry added desired result sample

Comment: So you only want those two columns in the result?

Comment: @Strawberry In my code just IDs will work as well but In this example I have given ID an price.

Comment: I which case, the answer provided below is just about as good as you're going to get.

Comment: @Strawberry I hope so, Because I have a complex query wrapping this query get more data about product.. that select translations and then sorting, but at end I just get Product id..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you want to get only one row with lowest price. So, when you have multiple rows with same price in a group, you'd need to decide which row you want. Perhaps with minimum `id`:

```
select min(p.id) as id,
    p.price
from product p
join (
    select product_group_id,
        min(price) as price
    from product
    group by product_group_id
    ) as inp
on  p.product_group_id = inp.product_group_id
    and p.price = inp.price
group by p.price, p.product_group_id;
```

Comment: Definitely you got the idea.. and it work fine. I will check this solution on my actual DB and give feedback.

Comment: Could you ditch the subquery and do that with a HAVING?

Comment: @CaiusJard I know that solution using HAVING, but that was very slow compared to this solution I just switched to this solution 2 months ago from HAVING. But feel free to suggest your solution

Comment: Interesting; i'd have expected it to be quicker. Actually with this kind of thing I'd use a window function, but MySQL doesn't have them :/

Comment: The final grouping criterion is redundant, but otherwise this is a good solution.

Comment: I managed to optimise this query by just using `p.id` instead of `min(p.id)` and only doing group by p.product_group_id on outer query it gave same results.  as for me it does not matter if its 1st or last product in group and `group by p.price` was also removed as second `group by p.product_group_id` was enough to group repeating groups.